# 403 on localhost: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: localhost, http-status-code-403

I'm using Wamp, and Im delevoping an php web application.
I'm not sure what exactly I changed, but for some reason I'm getting a 403 on my localhost now. Any Suggestions?

Comment: increase the file permission it seems you don't have sufficient permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know, but here are so many possible solutions http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

Answer (score 0):

Goto C:/wamp/alias/ 
open phpmyadmin.conf with a text editor
Find something like this (mentioned below) and replace it with one given here

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```